# jsreport.AspNetCore mvc page to PDF rendering intranet properly but different size while using from remote site

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, jsreport

jsreport.AspNetCore mvc page to PDF  rendering intranet properly but different size while using from remote site, please help css .invoice-box and the code is

```
 var header = await JsReportMVCService.RenderViewToStringAsync(HttpContext, RouteData, "Header", new { });
            var footer = await JsReportMVCService.RenderViewToStringAsync(HttpContext, RouteData, "footer", new { });
            HttpContext.JsReportFeature()
              .Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf)

             .Configure((r) => r.Template.Chrome = new Chrome
             {
                 Format= "A4",
                 HeaderTemplate = header,
                 FooterTemplate=footer,
                 DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
                 MarginTop = "3cm",
                 MarginLeft = ".5cm",
                 MarginBottom = "1cm",
                 MarginRight = ".5cm"
             }).OnAfterRender((r) => HttpContext.Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"myReport.pdf\"");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the issue as jsreport taking only inline css only  on remote execution